# Does QuickTime automatically record stereo audio into mono?

Tags: audio, quicktime

I connect Zoom h4n Pro to my Mac via USB as audio interface. I then record audios with QuickTime.

The input of h4n is stereo; the right & left inputs are not exactly the same. But it seems that QuickTime automatically mixes the left & right channels; as a result, the generated audio file has same volumes from left and right.

Could anyone confirm me that it is true?

Comment: Not an answer about Quicktime, but if you download GarageBand or similar you will have much more/better control. https://apps.apple.com/de/app/garageband/id682658836?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and my solution is pretty straightforward. I use ffmpeg to convert the audio to mono.

Install
[Brew](https://brew.sh/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Install ffmpeg:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Convert audio:

```
ffmpeg -i screenRecord.mov -ac 1 screenRecordMono.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue (Scarlett i2i USB hardware):

[Can't get QuickTime to record in stereo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412655/cant-get-quicktime-to-record-in-stereo)

I confirmed that Audacity records in stereo - even at the same time as QuickTime records in mono.

I called Apple and they were pretty clueless. It's possible (and painful) to detach the audio track from the QuickTime movie and attach the Audacity track instead - iMovie can be cajoled to do it reluctantly. I haven't found a better solution yet.