# Can't get QuickTime to record in stereo

Tags: mac, quicktime, recording, sound-volume

My setup is a MacBook Pro 2013 (Big Sur), connected to Scarlett 2i2 via USB.

The Scarlett has two channels, and I'm using two external microphones. My goal is to record music video with stereo sound.

QuickTime would only produce mono sound - I can see the bars on the L and R channels moving in sync when I tap either microphone (and of course can hear the mono result in the video).

If I record with Audacity, I get stereo sound. So it must be a software issue. In fact, I can record via both QuickTime and Audacity at the same time, and use iMovie to move the Audacity soundtrack to the movie clip, but it's such a pain.

Is there a way to convince QuickTime to record in stereo? Alternatively, is there another video recording software that can record stereo sound? I tried vlc, and couldn't get its weird recording interface to work.